# Security error while modifying web.xml

Tags: spring, apache, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring MVC, trying to implement Spring Security features. When I modify the `web.xml` file I get this kind of error in Catalina log:

```
27.11.2012 9:49:21 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

The `web.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>

    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/app-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--CharsetFilter start-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>kz.bimash.FoodSec.filters.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This code gives me an error, but when I tried to remove the Spring Security configuration part, it started to work fine. Could you correct my errors in `web.xml`?

Here is the Apache log file:

```
27.11.2012 10:57:37 org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component    [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/foodsec]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
27.11.2012 10:57:38 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/foodsec]
27.11.2012 10:57:38 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache Software  Foundation\tomcat7\conf\Catalina\localhost\foodsec.xml
27.11.2012 10:57:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
27.11.2012 10:57:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/foodsec] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: `SEVERE: Error listenerStart` means that your only listener (ContextLoaderListener) throw an exception or didn't finish, unfortunately without enough info from tomcat I can't say what's going on, can you put more logging info from tomcat?

Comment: I have updated and wrote the apache tomcat catalina log file,pls have a look

Comment: that won't help, what are you using any logging library? Try logging "org.sprinframework"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a problem with your multiple configs:

```
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
```

Try using a comma instead:

```
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
```

Best practice is to use wildcards, like this:

```
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
```

And then have your context files named as:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using some logging framework. (put logging framework jars on your classpath)
Without deploy logs no-one is going to help you (we don't like to guess).

Take a look at the tutorial: http://fauzimh.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/spring-3-framework-hello-world-using-eclipse-slf4j-and-logback/

So now enable SLF4J and Logback in your project.

After enabling it, you should get information in Tomcat logs why your Spring XML configuration is bad. Use that information to solve your problem. Yes, I think the problem is not in your `web.xml` but in your Spring context files.